# Is There a URI Format for Creating Alarms?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an application that will let a user select a time using a TimePicker, then create an **ACTION_VIEW** implicit intent with a **URI** identifying the selected time that can be received by any alarm application (like the default Android Alarms app).

I've tried using **URI**.parse with a string formatted in **"HH:MM"** format, but no apps are able to open the intent `(ie. ResolveActivity == null)`. I've also tried to find some succinct listing of URI formats and how/when to use them, but I pretty much came up empty.

Is this possible? Or is there some other way for my app to create an alarm in an alarm application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Common Intents documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#CreateAlarm), you can use [`AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html#ACTION_SET_ALARM) to set an alarm:

```
val intent = Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM).apply {
    putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
    putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour)
    putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minutes)
}
if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
    startActivity(intent)
}
```